# Community evaluation #3 -- please posts your thoughts/comments here

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

Once again, we have a community evaluation. This is the same as last time, it's in the review queues.

Head [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/community-eval/) to participate.

Since the new queues don't really provide the option to add eval-specific comments (unlike [the old method](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169/chemistry-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical)), I'm setting up this meta post as suggested by the community team.

Feel free to post your thoughts on the eval questions as answers/comments here. There's no specific form to the answers, you may write one-answer-per-question (slightly clutter-y, though), or just keep all your opinions on all questions in one post. If you want some ideas as to what sort of comments we're looking for, read the [old eval](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169/chemistry-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical) and its comments.

Here's a list of the questions (so that you don't have to go back and look for them), numbered for convenience:

1. [Where can I find a downloadable spreadsheet of element properties?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/where-can-i-find-a-downloadable-spreadsheet-of-element-properties)
2. [Why does the conversion of SO₂ to SO₃ require high pressure?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/why-does-the-conversion-of-so-to-so-require-high-pressure)
3. [What is the process for purifying KOH?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2836/what-is-the-process-for-purifying-koh)
4. [How does the litmus pH indicator work?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/how-does-the-litmus-ph-indicator-work)
5. [Lennard Jones liquid vapor phase transition](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/lennard-jones-liquid-vapor-phase-transition)
6. [Ambiguity synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/ambiguity-synthesis)
7. [What makes Coke acidic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/what-makes-coke-acidic)
8. [Calculating heat capacity of a calorimeter](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/calculating-heat-capacity-of-a-calorimeter)
9. [What is a 'Trace Crossing'?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/what-is-a-trace-crossing)
10. [Why are nitrogenous hydrocarbons sometimes colorful?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/why-are-nitrogenous-hydrocarbons-sometimes-colorful)

Comment: Thanks for starting this!

Comment: @jonsca: Not my idea, [Anna's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166562/178438) (also some discussion in TL). I just decided to facilitate it since the automated post hasn't been implemented yet :)

Comment: I guess this is going to be a little off topic, but is the beta going to survive :)? Is it still growing? Will it get removed if it doesn't start doing better?

Comment: @Brian: It's growing, that's for sure. And it has much better stats than the betas that were closed a while back :) That doesn't guarantee it's survival, but I don't think we have to worry much about it.

Comment: @Brian oh, btw, the fact that we _have_ a community eval has nothing to do with the survival of the site (aside from the obvious "it's still alive!"). Evals are automatic events, the occur every 90 days.

Comment: @Manishearth I totally missed that, I'm so behind the times.  Next thing you know they'll be telling me that tube TVs are obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

I think most of that content is good, and lives up to the standards I've witnessed on other stack exchanges. I could wish for more activity, but that will hopefully pick up in time. Maybe we should encourage self-answering questions some more, just to build content that will attract more new users?

Comment: I'm happy that you feel that the quality is pretty good  :) Activity, well, yeah, we're picking up speed, which is good. Not sure about self-answering questions; it's not that good an idea to "seed" the site (no rule against it though). However, if you have something _awesome_ to share, and can put it in a Q&A form, feel free to do so! Similarly for any problem/curiosity which you have recently faced and solved yourself.

Answer (score 0):

We seem to have a good crop this time (I didn't have to click "needs improvement" even once!). The quality/informativeness of the answers is quite high. I don't like all the questions, but the answers make up for a lot of it :)

Once the eval is over (and after confirming this with the other mods), I shall post some graphs of the results.

---

Individual remarks (it's better if you first do the eval, and *then* read these):

1. [Where can I find a downloadable spreadsheet of element properties?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/where-can-i-find-a-downloadable-spreadsheet-of-element-properties)

   > I don't like recommendation/reference request qs much. But this one seems highly useful, and the nice answer by Richard makes up for it :) I voted "Satisfactory", since the question type wasn't so good, and the answer made up for it.
2. [Why does the conversion of SO₂ to SO₃ require high pressure?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/why-does-the-conversion-of-so-to-so-require-high-pressure)

   > I like the question. Though it is a simple one, it begs for a detailed explanation. Which is what it got. "Excellent" from me.
3. [What is the process for purifying KOH?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2836/what-is-the-process-for-purifying-koh)

   > DIY question -- not my favorite type, but there's nothing *bad* about it :) A good recommendation in the answer, though it would help if the answer had some info on *why* it works.
4. [How does the litmus pH indicator work?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/how-does-the-litmus-ph-indicator-work)

   > Rather common question (this is good!), with a good answer. I voted "Satisfactory", but on rereading it I probably should've given it "Excellent"
5. [Lennard Jones liquid vapor phase transition](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/lennard-jones-liquid-vapor-phase-transition)

   > A detailed question on an actual problem that is faced. Such questions are rare on science sites -- generally "actual problem I face" questions are too localised. "Excellent" for that reason itself. Good answer, though a bit short.
6. [Ambiguity synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/ambiguity-synthesis)

   > Slightly incomplete question, with a short answer. "Satisfactory", leaning towards "Needs Improvement"
7. [What makes Coke acidic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/what-makes-coke-acidic)

   > Good question, with OK answers (they're rather speculative -- though I'm not sure how far you can go here before having to whip out pKa and concentration values) "Satisfactory"
8. [Calculating heat capacity of a calorimeter](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/calculating-heat-capacity-of-a-calorimeter)

   > A homework question with some effort in it! Yay! The second answer is against our HW policy (it's a complete answer -- we only provide hints). "Satisfactory", since an "Excellent" HW problem in my eyes will have to be truly excellent :P
9. [What is a 'Trace Crossing'?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/what-is-a-trace-crossing)

   > Terminology question. Not my favorite type. Useful, though. Another "satisfactory"
10. [Why are nitrogenous hydrocarbons sometimes colorful?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/why-are-nitrogenous-hydrocarbons-sometimes-colorful)

    > Good question about color, with a good answer. "Satisfactory", leaning towards "Excellent"

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep some graphs regarding the evals here. Their design is inspired (and largely copied) from the ones on [genealogy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/community-eval-finished) and [gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6858/community-evaluation-results-2-february-2013).

When I refer to Net Score here, I mean "(number of "excellent" reviews)-(number of "needs improvement" reviews)"

#### Distribution of evaluation votes received by type (along with net score)

[image]

#### Net score plotted with question/answer scores (by votes)

[image]

I may post more graphs later--these are the ones which give the most insights IMO. If you have any ideas for a graph, please let me know. (Or ping me, I'll be happy to provide the data in a nice format)

Answer (score -1):

## Final Results

- [What is the process for purifying KOH?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2836/what-is-the-process-for-purifying-koh)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How does the litmus pH indicator work?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/how-does-the-litmus-ph-indicator-work)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Lennard Jones liquid vapor phase transition](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/lennard-jones-liquid-vapor-phase-transition)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Where can I find a downloadable spreadsheet of element properties?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/where-can-i-find-a-downloadable-spreadsheet-of-element-properties)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why does the conversion of SO₂ to SO₃ require high pressure?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2829/why-does-the-conversion-of-so-to-so-require-high-pressure)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Calculating heat capacity of a calorimeter](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/calculating-heat-capacity-of-a-calorimeter)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Why are nitrogenous hydrocarbons sometimes colorful?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/why-are-nitrogenous-hydrocarbons-sometimes-colorful)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What makes Coke acidic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/what-makes-coke-acidic)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Ambiguity in synthesis (crystallization)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/ambiguity-synthesis)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What is a 'Trace Crossing'?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/what-is-a-trace-crossing)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

Comment: Ah, thanks for this :) I totally forgot to make the graphs and all (got an exam going on). I'll do them later.

Comment: @Manishearth Cool; no worries. Don't edit this answer though if/when you do - I'm trying to use it as an example for future automatically posted results.

Comment: No prob, I'll post it separately :) [and yep, I forgot _again_ ] _bangs head against wall_